# jQuery .removeAttr('style') after .animate() does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I've got the following nav

```
<nav>
   <a href="#" class="current">HOME</a>
   <a href="#">ABOUT</a><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```

with this styling:

```
nav a {
    font-family: monospace;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 114px;
    height: 29px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #004870;
}
nav a {
    margin-left: 7px;
}
nav a.current{
    background-color: #585858;
    color: white;
}
```

And want to animate the BG color on `mouseover` to `#585858` and back to `#a3a3a3` after `mouseleave` and the style attribute to get removed again.

I tried this code but the style attribute remains after `mouseleave`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('nav a:not(.current)').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).stop().animate( {
          backgroundColor: '#585858'
   }, 300);
});
$('nav a:not(.current)').mouseleave(function() {
$(this).stop().animate( {
    backgroundColor: '#004870'
}, 300).removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

So what changes are needed to remove the style attribute after the animation finished?

Comment: You can try out hover() function. Also use callback function of animate to remove the style attribute.

Comment: Does [animate backgroundColor](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties) work? `For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the `[jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) `plugin is used`

Comment: I was actually using the jQueryUI Color plugin, as "I tried this code but the style attribute remains after ´mouseleave´" might have implied

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing here the fact, that `jQuery.animate` is asynchronous, so your `removeAttr` is called before the animation finishes. You should use the complete callback to call `removeAttr`.

You also need the [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin for `jQuery.animate` to be able to animate `background-color`.

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.stop().animate({ backgroundColor: jQuery.Color("rgb(0, 72, 112)") }, {
    duration: 300,
    complete: function() { $this.removeAttr('style') }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the jquery-ui plugin [to animate color](http://jqueryui.com/animate/). Take a look at your code including the current jquery ui: http://jsfiddle.net/sUeBd/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('nav a:not(.current)').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: '#585858'
    }, 300);
  });
  $('nav a:not(.current)').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: '#004870'
    }, 300).removeAttr('style');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change the background-color with animate...if you need to then  you have to use `jQuery.Color()` plugin. u can just load jquery ui plugin for this

according to the docs..

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (**For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used**). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) here

and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YpmXR/1/) with ui plugin

Answer (score 0):

jQuery cannot animate colors but you can add jQuery plugin like this

```
<script src="http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gRTHv/1/

Answer (score 0):

a `CSS3` version that requires `Chrome`, `Safari`, `Opera`, `Firefox 5+` or `IE10`

```
nav a:not(.current) { 
    animation:navOut 1s forwards; 
}

nav a:not(.current):hover { 
    animation:navOver 1s forwards; 
}

@keyframes navOver { 
    to { background-color:#a3a3a3; } 
}

@keyframes navOut { 
    from { background-color:#a3a3a3; } 
    to { background-color:#004870;} 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbaris/d6msw/

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this event with CSS. No need to use java script.

Update your css code with this one

```
nav a 
{
    font-family: monospace;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 114px;
    height: 29px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background:#a3a3a3;
}
nav a {
    margin-left: 7px;
}
nav a.current{
     background:#585858;
    color: white;
}
nav a:hover{
    background:#585858;
}
```

Check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uTYFC/2/